# namespace on python pickle

Tags: python, namespaces, pickle

I got an error when I use pickle with unittest.

I wrote 3 program files:

1. for a class to be pickled,
2. for a class which use class in #1,
3. unittest for testing class in #2.

and the real codes are as follows respectively.

#1. ClassToPickle.py

```
import pickle
class ClassToPickle(object):
    def __init__(self, x):
        self.x = x
if __name__=="__main__":
    p = ClassToPickle(10)
    pickle.dump(p, open('10.pickle', 'w'))
```

#2. SomeClass.py

```
from ClassToPickle import ClassToPickle
import pickle

class SomeClass(object):
    def __init__(self):
        self.pickle = pickle.load(open("10.pickle", 'r'))
        self.x = self.pickle.x
        print self.x

if __name__ == "__main__":
    SomeClass()
```

#3. SomeClassTest.py

```
import unittest
from SomeClass import SomeClass
from ClassToPickle import ClassToPickle # REQUIRED_LINE

class SomeClassTest(unittest.TestCase):
    def testA(self):
        sc = SomeClass()
        self.assertEqual(sc.x, 10)

def main():
    unittest.main()

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

I ran #1 program first to make pickle file.
And then, when I run program file #2 alone (i.e. enter "python SomeClass.py"), it works.
And, when I run program #3 alone (i.e. enter "python SomeClassTest.py"), it also works.

However, when I run program #3 as "unit-test" in eclipse+pydev, it returns an error message below.

> ======================================================================
>   ERROR: testA (SomeClassTest.SomeClassTest)
>   ----------------------------------------------------------------------
>   Traceback (most recent call last):
> $ File
>   "/home/tmp/pickle_problem/SomeClassTest.py", line 9, in
>   testA
>       sc = SomeClass()
> $ File "/home/tmp/pickle_problem/SomeClass.py", line 8, in
>   **init**
>       self.pickle = pickle.load(open("10.pickle", 'r'))
> $ File "/usr/lib/python2.7/pickle.py", line 1378, in load
>       return Unpickler(file).load()
> $ File "/usr/lib/python2.7/pickle.py", line 858, in load
>       dispatchkey
>  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/pickle.py", line 1090, in load_global
>       klass = self.find_class(module, name)
> $ File "/usr/lib/python2.7/pickle.py", line 1126, in find_class
>       klass = getattr(mod, name)
> $  AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'ClassToPickle'
>  
>   ----------------------------------------------------------------------
>  Ran 1 test in 0.002s
>             
>  FAILED (errors=1)

And also, when I commented out a line that import ClassToPickle class (line 3 in program #3 and commented as "REQUIRED_LINE"), It doesn't work and return an error message described below.

> E
>   ======================================================================
>   ERROR: testA (**main**.SomeClassTest)
>   ----------------------------------------------------------------------
>   Traceback (most recent call last):
>     File "SomeClassTest.py", line 9, in testA
>       sc = SomeClass()
>     File "/home/tmp/pickle_problem/SomeClass.py", line 8, in **init**
>       self.pickle = pickle.load(open("10.pickle", 'r'))
>     File "/usr/lib/python2.7/pickle.py", line 1378, in load
>       return Unpickler(file).load()
>     File "/usr/lib/python2.7/pickle.py", line 858, in load
>       dispatchkey
>     File "/usr/lib/python2.7/pickle.py", line 1090, in load_global
>       klass = self.find_class(module, name)
>     File "/usr/lib/python2.7/pickle.py", line 1126, in find_class
>       klass = getattr(mod, name)
>   AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'ClassToPickle'
>   
>   ----------------------------------------------------------------------
>   Ran 1 test in 0.001s
>   
>   FAILED (errors=1)

I guess the problem is about namespace in python, but I don't know what happened exactly and what can I do for resolving it.

How can I "run as unit-test (in eclipse+pydev)" #3 program correctly,
and run #3 program in command line without the line which imports ClassToPickle?
Please help me.

Comment: Is there another `ClassToPickle.py` file anywhere that it could be finding instead of the file you've shown here?

Comment: @ThomasK Thanks for your comment, but the answer is No. Only three .py files shown here are in the directory, and I've never create file named `ClassToPickle.py`.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

That because `__main__.ClassToPickle != ClassToPickle.ClassToPickle`, think of it like this:

When you pickled the class instance of ClassToPickle in the `ClassToPickle.py` script, the pickle module will pickle all the reference to the class which mean it will pickle the module name where the class was defined, and because you executed the script `ClassToPickle.py` this mean that the module will be set to `__main__` which mean that `pickle` module will pickle `__main__.ClassToPickle`.

And when you tried to load the pickled instance it fail because it didn't find the instance's class which is `__main__.ClassToPickle` and not the one that you imported using `from ClassToPickle import ClassToPickle` because this latest is `ClassToPickle.ClassToPickle`.

A fix will be to create another script that will handle dumping instead of doing it in `ClassToPickle.py` e.g.

```
import pickle

from ClassToPickle import ClassToPickle

if __name__=="__main__":
    p = ClassToPickle(10)
    pickle.dump(p, open('10.pickle', 'w'))
```

Comment: Thanks for your explanation! It all made sense to me, and your script works both in console and eclipse:)