# More on python ImportError No module named

Tags: python, pickle, importerror

Following the suggestion [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/338768/python-importerror-no-module-named), my package (or the directory containing my modules) is located at C:/Python34/Lib/site-packages. The directory contains an `__init__.py` and `sys.path` contains a path to the directory as shown.

[image]

Still I am getting the following error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Python34/Lib/site-packages/toolkit/window.py", line 6, in <module>
    from catalogmaker import Catalog
  File "C:\Python34\Lib\site-packages\toolkit\catalogmaker.py", line 1, in <module>
    from patronmaker import Patron
  File "C:\Python34\Lib\site-packages\toolkit\patronmaker.py", line 4, in <module>
    class Patron:
  File "C:\Python34\Lib\site-packages\toolkit\patronmaker.py", line 11, in Patron
    patrons = pickle.load(f)
ImportError: No module named 'Patron'
```

I have a class in patronmaker.py named 'Patron' but no module named Patron so I am not sure what the last statement in the error message means. I very much appreciate your thoughts on what I am missing.

**Python Version 3.4.1** on a Windows 32 bits machine.

Comment: What are you unpickling, and when/how was it pickled?  You could be running into an issue like [this one](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2121874/python-pickling-after-changing-a-modules-directory).

Comment: I have 4 modules each containing several lines of code and pickle files all interacting together. Is it optimal to post these?  Thoughts?

Comment: Using pickle for data persistence to save 2 dictionaries and l list.

Comment: try `pprint`ing pythons `sys.path` on a line before the exception and verify that any referenced paths are relative to one of the sys paths? Just shooting in the dark here.

Comment: @BrenBarn Great suggestion. However, the pickle issue you pointed may likely not be at play here. I deleted all pickle files and the program still returns the same errors, except for the last line in the traceback which now reads: `AttributeError: Can't get attribute 'Patron' on <module '__main__' from 'C:/Python34/Lib/site-packages/toolkit/window.py'>`. So it seems I no longer have ImportError but rather AttributeError.

Comment: How are you running your code?  Remember that when you run a script, its module name will be `__main__` instead of its regular name, so that could disrupt pickle's attempt to import.  Are you running patronmaker.py directly?

Comment: @ThorSummoner I read the documentation on pprint [here](https://docs.python.org/3/library/pprint.html) but I am not sure how it applies here or how to implement it.

Comment: @BrenBarn I am using PyCharm. One of my modules, window.py, has `if __name__ == "__main__":

    app = Gui()`. Gui is the only class in window.py. Am I doing it correctly?

Comment: I will pick up your feedback tomorrow. It's 2:08 AM here. Meanwhile, thanks all!

Comment: @BrenBarn: I think you are probably right. It's hard to tell how to address it without seeing the code.  @sedeh, if you try to use `dill` instead of `pickle`, this may solve your problem.  `pickle` serializes classes by reference, and doesn't play well with `__main__` for many objects.  In `dill`, you don't have to serialize `classes` by reference, and it can handle issues with `__main__`, much better.  Get `dill` here: https://github.com/uqfoundation

Comment: OK. I just pushed the modules to the github repo [here](https://github.com/sedeh/TerritorySystem). I was window.py. I hope this helps.

Comment: @sedeh I suggested pprint for use as a debugging tool, for easier reading of the sys.path output.

Comment: @ThorSummoner OK, I inserted `from pprint import pprint
pprint(vars())` before importing the modules. I got the output [here](http://ideone.com/GV41bL). Not sure what to make of it. Using `import pdb pdb.set_trace()` at the same location produced `C:\Python34\python.exe C:/Python34/Lib/site-packages/toolkit/window.py
> c:\python34\lib\site-packages\toolkit\window.py(8)<module>()
-> from catalogmaker import *
(Pdb)`

Comment: Here is a more complete pdb step through of window.py. http://ideone.com/YRyrdf

Comment: @sedeh Oh, I'm not interested in your vars, I'm interested in the sys.path `import sys; pprint(sys.path)`, I am not sure I can really offer much help even if you do provide such information; I only would guess you should see the containing folder for your module in that path to know its not a path issue.

Comment: You should show **what** caused the traceback, not just the traceback.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are saving all patron instances (i.e. `self`) to the `Patron` class attribute `Patron.patrons`.  Then you are trying to pickle a class attribute from within the class.  This can choke `pickle`, however I believe `dill` should be able to handle it.  Is it really necessary to save all the class instances to a list in Patrons?  It's a bit of an odd thing to do…

`pickle` serializes classes by reference, and doesn't play well with `__main__` for many objects. In `dill`, you don't have to serialize classes by reference, and it can handle issues with `__main__`, much better. Get `dill` here: https://github.com/uqfoundation

**Edit:**
I tried your code (with one minor change) and it worked.

```
dude@hilbert>$ python patronmaker.py
```

Then start python…

```
>>> import dill
>>> f = open('patrons.pkl', 'rb')
>>> p = dill.load(f)
>>> p
[Julius Caeser, Kunte Kinta, Norton Henrich, Mother Teresa]
```

The only change I made was to uncomment the lines at the end of `patronmaker.py` so that it saved some patrons…. and I also replaced `import pickle` with `import dill as pickle` everywhere.

So, even by downloading and running your code, I can't produce an error with `dill`. I'm using the latest `dill` from github.

**Additional Edit:**
Your traceback above is from an `ImportError`.  Did you install your module?  If you didn't use setup.py to install it, or if you don't have your module on your `PYTHONPATH`, then you won't find your module regardless of how you are serializing things.

**Even more edits:**
Looking at your code, you should be using the **singleton pattern** for `patrons`… it should not be inside the `class Patron`.  The block of code at the class level to load the patrons into `Patron.patrons` is sure to cause problems… and probably bound to be the source of some form of errors. I also see that you are pickling the attribute `Patrons.patrons` (not even the class itself) from inside the `Patrons` class -- **this is madness** -- don't do it.  Also notice that when you are trying to obtain the patrons, you use `Patron.patrons`… this is calling the class object and not an instance.  Move patrons outside of the class, and use the singleton directly as a list of patrons.  Also you should typically be using the patrons instance, so if you wanted to have each patron know who all the other patrons are, `p = Patron('Joe', 'Blow')`, then `p.patrons` to get all patrons… but you'd need to write a `Patrons.load` method that reads the singleton list of patrons… you could also use a `property` to make the `load` give you something that looks like an attribute.

If you build a singleton of patrons (as a list)… or a "registry" of patrons (as a dict) if you like, then just check if a patrons pickle file exists… to load to the registry… and don't do it from inside the Patrons class… things should go much better.  Your code currently is trying to load a class instance on a class definition while it *builds* that class object.  That's bad...

Also, don't expect people to go downloading your code and debugging it for you, when you don't present a minimal test case or sufficient info for how the traceback was created.
You *may* have hit on a valid pickling error in `dill` for some dark corner case, but I can't tell b/c I can't reproduce your error.  However, I can tell that you need some refactoring.

And just to be explicit:

Move your patrons initializing mess from Patrons into a new file `patrons.py`

```
import os
import dill as pickle

#Initialize patrons with saved pickle data
if os.path.isfile('patrons.pkl'):
    with open("patrons.pkl", 'rb') as f:
        patrons = pickle.load(f)
else: patrons = []
```

Then in patronmaker.py, and everywhere else you need the singleton…

```
import dill as pickle
import os.path
import patrons as the

class Patron:

    def __init__(self, lname, fname):
        self.lname = lname.title()
        self.fname = fname.title()
        self.terrCheckedOutHistory = {}
        #Add any created Patron to patrons list
        the.patrons.append(self)
        #Preserve this person via pickle
        with open('patrons.pkl', 'wb') as f:
            pickle.dump(the.patrons, f)
```

And you should be fine unless your code is hitting one of the cases that attributes on modules can't be serialized because they were added dynamically (see https://github.com/uqfoundation/dill/pull/47), which should definitely make `pickle` fail, and in some cases `dill` too… probably with an `AtrributeError` on the module.  I just can't reproduce this… and I'm done.

Comment: You are very correct and thanks for pinpointing the problem. Before getting into dill, let me try to implement the solution here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7928450/namespace-on-python-pickle. Your explanation and that of mouad in that post perfectly captures what is wrong with my problem.

Comment: Even with dill, the error persists. Calling dump on dill works fine but calling load on the picked data still throws error: `AttributeError: Can't get attribute 'Patron' on <module 'patronmaker' from 'C:\\Python34\\Lib\\site-packages\\toolkit\\patronmaker.py'>`.

Comment: I just downloaded your code, and what I tried worked.  I'm using python `3.4.1` on a Mac.

Comment: Thanks Mike for the teaching points! And sorry for the run around. I will do better next time.

Comment: You should post exactly what you sent me in an email.  When I saw your  full traceback, and what triggered it, it tells me that you are most likely running into the problem I mentioned above in the link to the `dill` github page. It's a corner case of pickling a dynamically edited module… and what is causing the `AttributeError` you are seeing. You'll need to do some refactoring -- and I would again suggest building something that stores your list of patron instances that is not inside the Patrons class.  The answer to that stack overflow question you liked above applies here.

Comment: To be clear, you should refactor so `dump` and `load` are being done by the same file, and neither are `__main__`, regardless of how you run the code (from `window.py` or from `patronmaker.py` or from the interpreter).

Comment: I refactored so that `dump` and `load` are being done by the same file. I used global variable so that the `dump` and `load` functions can access the same list. It worked! I used pickle, but I am sure dill can handle the task too. Thanks Mike for your useful feedback.