# Load pickled object in different file - Attribute error

Tags: python, python-3.x, pickle

I have some trouble with loading a pickled file in a module that is different from the module where I pickled the file. I am aware of the following thread: [Unable to load files using pickle and multipile modules](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27732354/unable-to-load-files-using-pickle-and-multipile-modules). I've tried the proposed solution of importing the class into the module where I am unpickling my file, but it keeps giving me the same error:
`AttributeError: Can't get attribute 'Document' on <module '__main__' from ''>`

The basic structure of what I am trying to do:

Util file that pickles and unpickles objects, utils.py:

```
import pickle

def save_document(doc):

    from class_def import Document

    write_file = open(file_path, 'wb')
    pickle.dump(doc, write_file)

def load_document(file_path):
    from class_def import Document

    doc_file = open(file_path, 'rb')
    return pickle.load(doc_file)
```

File where Document object is defined and the save util method is called, class_def.py:

```
import utils

class Document(object):
    data = ""

if __name__ == '__main__':
    doc = Document()
    utils.save_document(doc)
```

File where the load util method is called, process.py:

```
import utils

if __name__ == '__main__':
     utils.load_document(file_path)
```

Running process.py gives the mentioned AttributeError. If I import the class_def.py file into process.py and run its main method as mentioned in the original thread it works, but I want to be able to run these two modules separately, since the class_def file is a preprocessing step that takes quite some time. How could I solve this?

Comment: Doesn't answer your question, but you should close the file handlers after you've opened them, or simply use [`with`](http://effbot.org/zone/python-with-statement.htm).

Comment: when a file is being run as `__main__` anything that are defined in it are pickled as members of the `__main__` module, so if you are then loading into a different file it fails.  You need to only pickle things from modules other then the `__main__` the quickest fix is `from <this modules name> import *` but I do not recommend it in production code.

Comment: possible duplicate of [namespace on python pickle](http://stackoverflow.com/q/7928450/5827215) but I think there might be a better thread to mark as dup

Comment: check this thread https://stackoverflow.com/a/51397373/7429675, you can do something like this

Answer (score 27, accepted):

in your `class_def.py` file you have this code:

```
if __name__ == '__main__':
    doc = Document()
    utils.save_document(doc)
```

This means that `doc` will be a `__main__.Document` object, so when it is pickled it is expecting to be able to get a `Document` class from the main module, to fix this you need to use the definition of `Document` from a module called `class_def` meaning you would add an import here:

(in general you can just do `from <own module name> import *` right inside the `if __name__ == "__main__"`)

```
if __name__ == '__main__':
    from class_def import Document 
    # ^ so that it is using the Document class defined under the class_def module
    doc = Document()
    utils.save_document(doc)
```

that way it will need to run the class_def.py file twice, once as `__main__` and once as `class_def` but it does mean that the data will be pickled as a `class_def.Document` object so loading it will retrieve the class from the correct place.  Otherwise if you have a way of constructing one document object from another you can do something like this in `utils.py`:

```
def save_document(doc):
    if doc.__class__.__module__ == "__main__":
        from class_def import Document #get the class from the reference-able module
        doc = Document(doc) #convert it to the class we are able to use


    write_file = open(file_path, 'wb')
    pickle.dump(doc, write_file)
```

Although usually I'd prefer the first way.

Comment: Amazing answer!

Answer (score 2):

I had a similar problem and only just realized the differences between our implementations.

**Your file structure:**

- util.py

  - define pickle functions
- class_def.py

  - import util
  - define class
  - make instance
  - call save pickle
- process.py

  - import util
  - load pickle

**My mistake (using your file names) was first:**

- util_and_class.py

  - define class
  - define pickle funcs
  - make instance
  - call save pickle
- process.py

  - import util_and_class
  - call load pickle << ERROR

**What solved my pickle import problem:**

- util_and_class.py

  - define class
  - define pickle funcs
- pickle_init.py

  - import util_and_class
  - make instance
  - call save pickle
- process.py

  - call load pickle

This had the welcomed side effect that I didn't need to import the util_and_class file as it's baked into the pickle file. Calling the instance and saving the pickle in a separate file resolved the `__name__` issue of *"loading a pickled file in a module that is different from the module where I pickled the file."*